# What is the name of this style of USB C receptacle with shield integrated into case?

Tags: usb, identification, connector

Is there a name for this kind of USB C receptacle seen here on a Macbook Pro where the shield is integrated into case and only the interface is mounted to the PCB?

[image]

Comment: In all likelihood this is an entirely custom part.

Answer (score 2):

The generic name for the sub-component of a connectors that contains the contacts is "insert". That term is mostly used when discussing circular connectors. But I would use the same term in this case of an exterior data I/O connector, for however rare it may be.

(I am referring to each of those two tabs with the contacts, not to the entire flex circuit assembly.)